# Q: Creating and running own planet map with openlayer

Tags: openlayers-3

I would like to create a osm like map for a fantasy planet.
Which already brings me to my questions:

Can I use openlayers-3 for a map that is not the map of the earth?
How do I create my own tiles for this planet? Is there a guide that you maybe can recommend?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'd have to design your map first, and then encode it into a format that OpenLayers uses, such as a KML Polgon file, PostGIS database, SHP Shapefile etc.

Tools like [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) would possibly be a good place to start building your map, adding details etc.  Then you can export them to one of the supported formats and point OpenLayers at it to be rendered.

N.B.  NEVER done this, so a lot of the above is conjecture.

Comment: Great tool, thank you! Will read into it, but this looks like it could work ;)